# How to affect a function to a variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, promise

I have the following two function that return promises ( if I m correct we call it promises correct me if I m wrong )

**fullscreenSource**

```
function fullscreenSource(id) {
    function search(child, id) {

        if (child !== undefined) {

            if (child.id === id || child.code === id) {
                console.log(id);
                console.log(child.id);
                return child.sourceFullScreen;
            } else {
                if (child.children !== undefined && child.children.length > 0) {
                    for (let index = 0; index < child.children.length; index++) {
                        data = undefined;
                        data = search(child.children[index], id);
                        if (data !== undefined) return data;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }

    return search(camSourceRepo.getAll(), id);
}
```

**normalSource**

```
function screenSource(id) {
    function search(child, id) {

        if (child !== undefined) {

            if (child.id === id || child.code === id) {
                console.log(id);
                console.log(child.id);
                return child.source;
            } else {
                if (child.children !== undefined && child.children.length > 0) {
                    for (let index = 0; index < child.children.length; index++) {
                        data = undefined;
                        data = search(child.children[index], id);
                        if (data !== undefined) return data;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }

    //console.log(camSourceRepo.getAll());
    return camSourceRepo.getAll().then(cams => {
        console.log(cams)
        return search(cams, id);
    })


}
```

I got the idea to use them in a functional fassion . like this :

```
let _screenSource = screenSource(p1);
if(div_prefix.includes("fullplayer_"))_screenSource = fullscreenSource(p1);

console.log(_screenSource)
_screenSource.then(source => {
    console.log(source);   
   });
```

**EDIT**

trying to use the funciton reference doesn't work

```
let _screenSource = screenSource;
if(div_prefix.includes("fullplayer_"))_screenSource = fullscreenSource;

console.log(_screenSource)
_screenSource(p1).then(source => {
    console.log(source);   
   });
```

However my `_screenSource` is undefined, Why ?

How to affect a function dynamically to a variable If POSSIBLE ??

Thanks

Comment: could you investigate those functions by logging them directly to the console.

Comment: the functions are working fine :) , I wanted to avoid boiler plate code, by using this affectation style.

Answer (score 0):

my `fullscreenSource(id)` is not in a promise flavor

updating it to this worked like a charm, next time we have to be worry about the return type.

```
async function fullscreenSource(id) {

    function search(child, id) {

        if (child !== undefined) {

            if (child.id === id || child.code === id) {
                console.log(id);
                console.log(child.id);
                return child.sourceFullScreen;
            } else {
                if (child.children !== undefined && child.children.length > 0) {
                    for (let index = 0; index < child.children.length; index++) {
                        data = undefined;
                        data = search(child.children[index], id);
                        if (data !== undefined) return data;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }

    //console.log(camSourceRepo.getAll());
    return camSourceRepo.getAll().then(cams => {
        console.log(cams)
        return search(cams, id);
    })

}
```